# go swagger how to add support for all mime type

Tags: mime-types, swagger, content-type, mime

Swagger by default supports application/json as Content type. And if I want to add other Content types then "produces" or "consumes" fields needs to updated in the swagger JSON file. Client may send any type of Data. Is there a way to support any Content type (remove the validation for Content type or regex like *) in swagger

Comment: I would love to know this as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have worked on go-swagger, you will have to mention in the swagger-spec file and generate the code again in order to do that. You can use */* to describe that the endpoint can generate all type of data. But you can not modify it after you have generated the code using go-swagger.

You can directly modify the generated files but it's not recommended.